# Auto Complete With Custom Values Not Saving Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Im implementing an auto complete UIText field like when entering a URL into Safari, and it shows previous URLs. A table view below the input field lists all of the potential options. Im using the Following tutorial,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Everything works fine, the problem is the tutorial and sample code shows no way to save the auto complete values in the table view with the custom values based on what the user entered. As soon as the view is navigated away from, all the saved data in the table view is gone.

Sample project

http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/AutoCompDemo.zip

I tried using `NSSUserDeafaults`in various configurations but I couldn't get it to save the data. I tried researching Google, the blog post for the tutorial and SO but cant find an answer to saving the custom data in the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the project a little to store typed URLs permanently in `NSUserDefaults`. You can download from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?9u3iimr30u3fyz3).

Comment: Thank you so much Khawar, that fixed it and was really easy to understand thanks to your modification and clear comments in code.  Thanks again. plus 1!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder` in your custom data modal class

See complete tutorial below

```
[Storing Custom objects in NSUserDefaults][1]
```